# SailsJS/Waterline: where in populated association

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have three models: `users`, `groups`, `subscribers`. There's a many-to-many relation between users and groups, through the group subscribers model.

I want to get a list of all groups the user is subscribed to, with all subscribers.

```
// Group model
subscriber: {
  collection: 'user',
  via: 'group',
  through: 'messagegroupsubscriber'
}

// Controller
Group.find().populate('subscriber').exec(function(err, grps) [
    return res.json(grps);
});
```

This returns **all** groups with subscribers - but I just want groups where the user is subscribed to (in this case: where the user id is within the subscriber attribute).

```
// Assuming the user ID is 1

// What I get
[
    {
        "groupID": 1,
        "name": "First group",
        "subscriber": [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "John"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "groupID": 2,
        "name": "Second group",
        "subscriber": []
    }
]

// What I WANT to get
[
    {
        "groupID": 1,
        "name": "First group",
        "subscriber": [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "John"
            }
        ]
    }
    // no more "Second group", since user ID "1" is not within the subscribers
]
```

Is this even possible with Waterline? If so, how? (otherwise I guess I need to switch to Sequelize or something similar, since I'll have a lot more complex queries in the future)

Comment: `Group.find().populate('subscriber', {where: { id: 1}})` It will return every subscriber with `id = 1` or `subscriber = null`

Comment: I don't want subscribers with a specific id - I want groups which contain a specific subscriber.

Comment: Oh... I don't think so. You can use [lodash.groupby()](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy)